# Is Memory-mapped-files as ipc between uwp app and win32 process supported

Tags: c#, windows, uwp, ipc, memory-mapped-files

The official docs doesn't properly state if ipc via memory-mapped-files is supported in uwp. I was working on a scenario for ipc between an uwp app and its desktop extension. While I can create memory-mapped-files using `System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles` from uwp app with `codeGeneration` capability but opening from win32 process fails with message `Unable to find the specified file.`. Is ipc via memory-mapped-files supported in uwp, if yes, what is the proper way to do it??

[Minimal reproduceable sample.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1_QGj5HncgvsrQwbc1IUUyGhHxA848_8f/view?usp=sharing)

### Update 1

[Updated sample implementing answer from @Peter Torr - MSFT.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fDdaW8iPP5e-ihzxzzyZLDKs1GXFg4KH/view?usp=sharing)

### Update 2

[Working sample in which memory-mapped-file created from uwp app can be read by win32 process.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1VkZOtuLYUP-wX_TGoqqqvs4S8uxRBIPi/view?usp=sharing) Reading memory-mapped-file in uwp app created by win32 process still isn't working.

Comment: Hello, according to the information in [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/interprocess-communication#shared-memory), there are some restrictions on shared memory. By default, only processes in the same package are allowed to access. If you meet these constraints, can you provide a minimum runnable demo so that we can analyze your problem?

Comment: @RichardZhang-MSFT added demo project. Feel free to test it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes it is supported, but if you're creating the object in a UWP context and opening it from a Desktop context then the Desktop process needs to explicitly use the namespace of the named object.

From within your UWP process, call [`GetAppContainerNamedObjectPath(nullptr, nullptr, ...)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/securityappcontainer/nf-securityappcontainer-getappcontainernamedobjectpath) to determine what that namespace is, and then add a backslash and your mapped file name to the end. It will be something like `AppContainerNamedObjects\S-1-15-2-xxxxxxx\YourMappedName`

You should only need to do this once, unless you change your package name (including the publisher hash). So once you have generated it, you can hard-code the value into your desktop app and forget about it.

Note that if you do it the other way around - Desktop creates the object, and UWP opens it - then you don't need to worry about the namespace, but you have to modify the access control instead, which is trickier.

Comment: Remember to use double-backslash if you need to in your string literals. The xxxxxx bit is specific to your app.

Comment: The sid string from `WebAuthenticationBroker.GetCurrentApplicationCallbackUri().Host` was lower case converting to upper case makes it work. Also, can you suggest how to do the reverse?? Reading memory-map created by desktop extension from uwp app??

Comment: Doing the reverse is a little more complicated and I wouldn't recommend it unless you really need it. If you mess up the code you could end up making the memory accessible to the wrong app.

Comment: Hi @PeterTorr-MSFT -- I'm attempting to create an event using CreateEventA from within a UWP app in order to communicate with a Win32 app and getting error code 3 (file not found):

CreateEventA(NULL, false, false, k_writerEventName)

Where: k_writerEventName = "AppContainerNamedObjects\\S-1-15-2-3950821806-2383410207-2205885981-1193157422-352231163-3160459235-648191853\\WriterEvent";

Any idea why this might be failing to create the event?

Comment: Is your string using double backslashes?

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT I know this is old but it was super useful for me, thanks for sharing! Could you provide a link or even better describe here how to do the reverse? I can open a new question for that if you want.

Comment: If you get it wrong, you can open security holes, but the basic approach is outlined here: [Sharing named objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/communication/sharing-named-objects).

Comment: @PeterTorr-MSFT managed to implement it, thanks for your support!